# How to stop NSTimer with another NSTimer?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

Note: I am using swift for this project.

I am currently working on my first project and I am trying to stop (invalidate) an NSTimer if a button was not pressed after a certain amount of time. I have found other ways of stopping my NSTimer but none saying how to stop it after a certain amount of time, with that time being reset if the button actually **is** pressed. Read everything to understand more clearly.

Here is my code now;

```
@IBOutlet var Text: UILabel!
var timer: NSTimer!
var countdown: Int = 0

@IBAction func StartGame(sender: AnyObject) {
self.countdown = 20
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: "updateCountdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateCountdown() {

    self.countdown--

    if self.countdown == 0 {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    let texts: NSArray = ["Test", "Testing"]
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(texts.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let textstring = texts.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)

    self.ColorText.text = textstring as? String
}

@IBAction func PlayerbuttonPRESSED(sender: AnyObject) {
if Text.text == "Test" {
//Something happens
}
if Text.text == "Testing" {
//Something happens 
}
```

What I am dying to know is how I make something else happen if the button was **not** pressed before ColorText.text was changed! (If the button was **not** pressed before changing the text after 1.5 seconds).

Ps. Sorry for the long code, I think it is necessary. :-)

Comment: You want to use NSNotifications. I'll link you apple docs. Basically you have to set up your class, Im assuming a view controller, to add it as an observer of a notification, Then send, or "post", that notification if the timer has counted down so many seconds since the last button press.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

-Read thoroughly and make sure you remove yourself as an observer after your app is done using the timer.

Comment: I am sorry @MatthewLawrenceBailey but I can not understand how I am going to use this to make an action to stop the other NSTimer? Thank you for your patience and help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this. One way, you could set bool value to true when the button is pressed then in `updateCountdown` check to the boolean.

For example:

```
func updateCountdown() {

     self.countdown--

    if self.countdown == 0 && YOUR_BUTTON_BOOL {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }  

    let texts: NSArray = ["Test", "Testing"]
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(texts.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let textstring = texts.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)

    self.ColorText.text = textstring as? String
}
```

However, using NSTimer in this fashion where you have it trigger in a short period of time like 1.5 seconds can become inaccurate. After the timer triggers 20 times the time past will be greater than 30 seconds. If accuracy is important you might be better off setting a second timer for 30 seconds. If the button is pressed it invalidates the 30 second timer if the 30 second timer fires it invalidates the 1.5 second timer.

Comment: I notice you are an expert, however, I am not very familiar with the Bool and Booleans. If you would take your time and show me what you mean with a second 30-second-timer and the Bool/Boolean in my coding, I would be forever grateful. @boidkan